# Who was the old guy with the last part of the device in the penultimate episode of Agents of Shield?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, character-identification, agents-of-shield

When the Agents of Shield assembled for the last time in the other timeline, who was the old guy who said the bus was late that brought the tuning fork?  Seems like lots of the things that happened in *Agents of Shield* have some sort of generational and social significance.  Since he was an old black man who had the last piece of the puzzle and according to the episode in the 1950's and prior there weren't any black people in Shield or its predecessor.  Was there some significance to this character? Could he have been a version of Old Man Mack from a yet another different timeline?

The episode is ["The End is at Hand"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt9307268/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast), second to last episode in season 7

The actor is [Bill Cobbs](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0167850/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t14) his credits do not have a name in the show in on the IMDB

Comment: So far no name has been given to the character after checking all of the usual common sources. It's likely it was just a cameo and an unnamed role though.

Comment: [*There is a strong possibility, even though the character’s name isn’t referenced directly, Cobbs plays Fury’s grandfather. There is brief reference to Fury’s grandfather in Captain America: The Winter Soldier and other productions which point us in that direction.*](https://medium.com/harsh-light-news/marvels-agents-of-s-h-i-e-l-d-s07-e12-e13-series-finale-3ea9e21a4481)